# Stretch Path to fill container

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

I have a resource defined like this:

```
<Canvas x:Key="export"
        Width="48"
        Height="48">
    <Path Fill="{DynamicResource CurrentColor}"
          Data="M23,12L19,8V11H10V13H19V16M1,18V6C1,4.89 1.9,4 3,4H15A2,2 0 0,1 17,6V9H15V6H3V18H15V15H17V18A2,2 0 0,1 15,20H3A2,2 0 0,1 1,18Z" />
</Canvas>
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Margin="10,5,10,10"
                Width="Auto"
                Height="Auto">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Rectangle Width="48"
                                Height="48"
                                Fill="{DynamicResource CurrentColor}">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                            Visual="{Binding}" />
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

As can be seen I'm trying to set the rectangle size to 48x48 but the Path Data coordinates in the resource were defined to draw it as 24x24. No matter what I try I cannot strech the resource to fill the button. How can it be done?

I'm open to change the button implementation if needed. All I need is to be able to show the icon in the button in a certain color.

Comment: Set Width and Height of the Path to 48 (instead of the Canvas) and its Stretch property to Fill. Why do you have the Canvas at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove canvas and use `Stretch="Uniform"` on the `Path`. If you want to reduce height/width of the `Path`, add it into eg. `Grid` or just set `Width` and `Height` of the `Path`:

```
<Grid Width="48" Height="48">
        <Path Fill="{DynamicResource CurrentColor}"
              Stretch="Uniform"
              Data="M23,12L19,8V11H10V13H19V16M1,18V6C1,4.89 1.9,4 3,4H15A2,2 0 0,1 17,6V9H15V6H3V18H15V15H17V18A2,2 0 0,1 15,20H3A2,2 0 0,1 1,18Z" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`

But then again if `Width` and `Height` are set they take precedence over the `Stretch` setting. See [Microsoft on HorizontalAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.horizontalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx).